# Binary tree crashing in C

Tags: c, function, crash, binary-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am starting to move into Binary trees in my C class. I understand the concept of a binary tree, but now I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of how it works. I tried to set up a simple binary tree that changes size based on what the user enters. Whenever I run the program it crashes after the first input. Could someone help me understand why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}node;

void traverse(node *root);
void addnode (node *root, int nUser);
int checknode (node *root, int nUser);

int main (void)
{
    int nUser;
    node *root;
    root=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root->value=10;
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter any integer, enter 0 when done\n\n\n"); /*Program crashes when I enter the first value, unsure why*/
        scanf("%d",&nUser);
        if(!(checknode(root,nUser)))/*check node runs through the binary tree to find the data if it exists, returns 1 if exists, 0 if it doesn't*/
            addnode(root,nUser); /*add node runs through the binary tree, when it finds a place where the number will fit, that is a null pointer where the number can be placed it will create a new node with the value and null pointers on right and left*/
    }while(nUser);
    traverse(root);/*should traverse the tree and print out values*/
    return(0);
}

void traverse(node *root)
{
    printf("%d/n",root->value);
    if(root->left)
        {
         traverse(root->left);
        }
    if(root->right)
        {
         traverse(root->right);
        }
}

void addnode (node *root, int nUser)
{
if(root->value<nUser)
    if(root->right)
        {
         addnode(root->right,nUser);
        }
    else
        {
        node *temp;
        temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->value=nUser;
        root->right=temp;
        }
if(root->value>nUser)
    if(root->left)
        {
         addnode(root->left,nUser);
        }
    else
        {
        node *temp;
        temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->value=nUser;
        root->left=temp;
        }
}
int checknode (node *root, int nUser)
{
    if(!(root->value==nUser))
    {
        if(root->value<nUser)
            if(root->right)
                {
                 checknode(root->right,nUser);
                }
            else
                {
                 return(0);
                }
        if(root->value>nUser)
            if(root->left)
                {
                 checknode(root->left,nUser);
                }
            else
                {
                 return(0);
                }
    }
    else
    {
        return (1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the `left` and `right` pointers of root are uninitialized when you pass root to `addnode`.  A buffer returned by `malloc` is not guaranteed to be NULL.

Try initializing `root->right` and `root->left` to NULL before the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
root=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Change to:

```
root=(node *)calloc(1, sizeof(node));
```

You didn't clear `root->left` and `root->right` to NULL, so you are using uninitialized pointers.  You should change all your `malloc` to `calloc`, or you need to clear your left and right pointers to NULL after each `malloc`.